I can not create Standard Registry on Guardian
I installed guardian using Docker. I added OPERATOR_ID, OPERATOR_KEY, IPFS_PROVIDER="web3storage", IPFS_STORAGE_KEY and IPFS_STORAGE_PROOF. But I can't create Standard Registry account.
I added .env and .env.docker file in guardian-service directory.

Is this a programming question?
